# Google actions table card output flashes and disappears in Nest Hub

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant

I see an issue while displaying a table card output in Nest hub, this used to work before. The table results appear for a second and then disappears forever. All other devices like google assistant in phone, simulator displays all seem to show the results as expected.
Not sure if something is broken after some automatic firmware upgrade, this is my firmware version 1.56.265669.
Is anyone facing this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Mine with similar firmware updated but never seen the new UI icon when swipe up from bottom. Guess this new feature is still under testing before launch to other countries region

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).